# Voting arrow colors are extremely low contrast

Tags: feature-request, design

I have a lot of difficulty telling whether or not I have selected a vote on CS stack exchange. The difficult is probably magnified by color blindness (Deuteranomaly, affects 5% of men).

[image: Voting arrows with up vote highlighted teal]

It's hard to establish whether or not the contrast is "too low" in an objective manner. In terms of brightness contrast, [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) gives only 1.10:1 (with 3:1 as a recommendation for foreground/background large print contrast).

A color more like this

[image: Voting arrows with up vote highlighted dark teal]

is much easier to distinguish and I think still "on-brand". (WebAIM gives it a brightness contrast ratio of 2.01:1).

Is there any hope the style can be adjusted to be clearer?

Comment: Huh. For me the current arrow is easier to distinguish from not having voted than what you propose.

Comment: @Gilles That's interesting, especially since the value is so much more different. But there are lots of variables, different eyes and different screens. The best compromise might be to leave it how it is, but I'd like to hear other opinions

Comment: Besides anatomy, screen settings also have an impact. For instance, I use redshift to adjust to 4500K during the day and 2700K at night. Never had a problem with the voting buttons, though!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there's hope! We're [revisiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps) themes throughout our network. Color-only solutions like this are bound to run into this type of issue, so we'll try our hardest to maintain an acceptable color contrast ratio.

Comment: As expressed in [my answer in the newer thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312384/156248), as long as the solution is "everybody gets the same boring triangle", I'm opposed. Adding additional visual cues for which toggles have been "depressed" is probably a good idea, though. Applies to the favorite and accepted elements as well.